# How do I stop a Kafka Producer from streaming the data?

Tags: apache-kafka, hadoop2

What is the command to gracefully stop/pause a Kafka producer from streaming data?

Comment: Which Kafka producer? Producers don't run within Kafka itself, they are external and call the Kafka producer API.

Comment: I have a Kafka producer listening to a streaming API. I want to stop listening to the same.

Comment: I'd like to help if I can but you didn't answer my question.

Comment: For example, if I am using Kafka to listen to the Twitter API. What do I do to stop doing that?
My understanding is that I connect a Kafka producer to the relevant API and then the data is sought by the consumer. So, I wanted to pause the producer in this case.

Comment: Kafka can't listen to the Twitter API, only another application can push Twitter API-fed events to Kafka. If you need to stop that application then it entirely depends on how that application works, which is independent of Kafka. Is this an actual problem you are having or a hypothetical question?

Comment: I am going through a tutorial. Thanks for the clarification, though.

Answer (score 2):

You could close producer by:

```
producer.close();
```

but don't forget call **producer.flush();** before close it.

Answer (score 0):

To stop a Producer from streaming data, you can just stop that application. (Kill its process, or just don't send any more data to a Kafka Broker.)

You can gracefully stop a Kafka Consumer from consuming streaming data, though.

According to the Kafka Definitive Guide, if you want to exit the infinite poll loop, you can call the consumer.wake() method.

> When you decide to exit the poll loop, you will need another thread to call consumer.wakeup(). If you are running the consumer loop in the main thread, this can be done from ShutdownHook. Note that consumer.wakeup() is the only consumer method that is safe to call from a different thread. Calling wakeup will cause poll() to exit with WakeupException, or if consumer.wakeup() was called while the thread was not waiting on poll, the exception will be thrown on the next iteration when poll() is called. The WakeupException doesn't need to be handled, but before exiting the thread, you must call consumer.close().

[Code Sample](https://github.com/gwenshap/kafka-examples/blob/master/SimpleMovingAvg/src/main/java/com/shapira/examples/newconsumer/simplemovingavg/SimpleMovingAvgNewConsumer.java)